# Mac can't detect external SSD

Tags: mac, ssd

I recently bought A XPG SSD (SX6000 Pro 1T) and an Orico case, to use as an external SSD drive.

When I plug it into my Mac mini (M1), it doesn't detect it. It doesn't even appear in Disk Utility.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

If the problem is with the SSD or the case, how can I be sure which one? I don't have another SSD nor another case to test it.

Comment: The only way to test it, at consumer level, is change each component & see which one makes it work again - SSD, enclosure, computer.

Comment: I'll see if I can find other components to test it, thanks.

Comment: Try another computer first if you can. It would rule out the mini being a problem. I had external drives that would only work on macOS and not Windows or v.v.

Comment: I tried with my phone, and it didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

First I would recommend verifying that your combo of SSD and SSD-enclosure work with a Windows PC, if available. This is the least demanding setup in regard to compatibility.

If that works, then a likely scenario is that your MacOS installation lacks the drivers to recognize the controller used by the SSD-enclosure. You may visit the enclosure's manufacturers website and see if they have drivers available for MacOS. Based on this [article](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/317715-early-adopters-of-apple-m1-macs-should-be-cautious-about-compatibility) it appears that some drivers need to be rewritten for M1 systems.

Comment: I managed to test it in another mac, and it worked. I believe it can be a driver issue.

Comment: Your test verifies a lot. Is the other Mac also an M1 system?

Comment: No, it's not an M1.

Comment: I managed to test it in a Mojave, and it didn't work

Comment: If it worked on one Mac system, then that confirms that the drive/enclosure is working and there is an Intel MacOS driver. If its not working with other systems/MacOS, then they either do not (yet) have that driver -> go to manufacturers website, or there is an issue with the USB connection -> try different ports.